# How to provide user id in mysql using Python

Tags: python, mysql, discord, discord.py, mysql-connector-python

I want to search for a user in a table by the user id from discord, but I can't provide the id in mysql. I get an error You have an error in your SQL syntax;
But I don't understand what's wrong.

```
    @commands.command()
    async def balance(self, ctx):
        create_balance(ctx)
        query = ("SELECT UserID FROM userdata "
                 "WHERE UserID = %s")

        user_id = ctx.message.author.id
        cur.execute(query, (user_id))
        for (UserID, score) in cur:
            print(UserID,score)
```

Comment: Your select query should include the "score" field. In this way:  `SELECT UserID,score FROM userdata`

Answer (score 3):

in python in conjunction  with mysql connector a tuple needs at least **2 dimensions**

so make

```
cur.execute(query, (user_id,))
```